# How to know limit of $\ln x$ approaches negative infinity as $x \to 0^+$?

Tags: limits, logarithms

So $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \ln x = -\infty$. If you draw the graph then it's very obvious. But without drawing a graph, how do we know it's $-\infty$ as opposed to $+\infty$?

Comment: Try to make substitutions in $\ln \color{red}{x}$ with very small values close to $0^+$ (for the $x$) and calculate the logarithm with the calculator (for example).

Comment: Which is the definition of $\log(x)$ that you're using?

Comment: Ok do you know that $\log x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty $? If yes, then just put $x=1/t$ and get $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\log t=-\infty$.

Comment: The fact that $\log x\to\infty $ as $x\to\infty $ follows from $\log (2^n)=n\log 2$ and $\log 2 >0$.

Comment: Also know that drawing a graph of a function makes use of various ideas from calculus like its limiting behavior at singularities, slopes and maxima minima. So your inferring a limit from a graph is circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we know $[\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\ln x]$ is $-\infty$ as opposed to $+\infty$?

Well, if $x<1$ then $\ln x<0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(e^{-n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}-n.$

Answer (score 2):

If you buy that $\lim\limits_{x\to \color{blue}{-\infty}} e^{x} = \color{red}{0}$, which you should since $e>1$, you can rephrase this using inverse functions to deduce $\lim\limits_{\xi \to \color{red}{0^+}} \ln(\xi)=\color{blue}{-\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Without being super rigorous, you know the function ${y=e^{x}}$ grows without bound as ${x\rightarrow \infty}$. This means

$${\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{-x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e^{x}}=0}$$

Which is equivalent to

$${\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}e^{x}=0}$$

And because the natural logarithm is meant to be the inverse of the exponential function, you can see that as ${x\rightarrow 0^{+}}$, ${\ln(x)}$ should diverge to ${-\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, applying L'Hôpital's rule, we see that
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \ln x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\ln x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln x+1}{1}=L+1$$

which implies that $L=\pm \infty$

Now just show $\ln(x)$ is decreasing to prove that $L=-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if
$
y=\phi(x)
$
is a monotone increasing function, then $x=\phi^{-1}(y)$ is also monotone increasing. In your case case $\phi^{-1}(y) = e^{y} = x$. Now, take $x \to 0^{+}$, you see that $e^{y}$ is monotone decreasing and tends to $0$.